# In JavaScript, from two array of objects I need to filter out objects based on a filter condition, in a new array in complexity less than O(n^2)

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity

**Explanation of the problem statement** : I have two arrays **A** and **B** :

```
A = [
     {
         "isAvailable" : true,
         "productCode" : "12103977",
         "size" : "UK/IND-3",
         "url" : "/asics-mens-gel-kayano-28-harmony-blue-running-shoes/12103977"
      },

      {
         "isAvailable" : true,
         "productCode" : "12103978",
         "size" : "UK/IND-4",
         "url" : "/asics-mens-gel-kayano-28-harmony-blue-running-shoes/12103978"
      },

      {
         "isAvailable" : true,
         "productCode" : "12103979",
         "size" : "UK/IND-8",
         "url" : "/asics-mens-gel-kayano-28-harmony-blue-running-shoes/12103979"
      },

]


B = [
       {
         "dimensionSize" : "3",
         "euroSize" : "36",
         "usSize" : "4"
      },

      {
         "dimensionSize" : "4",
         "euroSize" : "36",
         "usSize" : "4"
      },

      {
         "dimensionSize" : "10",
         "euroSize" : "36",
         "usSize" : "4"
      },
]
```

I need to create a **new array** **C** basis the below condition :

**Condition** : *"If the value contained in "**size**" key of any object in **array A** includes the value contained in key "**dimensionSize**" of any object in **array B** then add the corresponding matching object from **array B to array C**".*

So array C will look like this after the above condition is met -

```
C = [
      {
         "dimensionSize" : "3", 
         "euroSize" : "36",
         "usSize" : "4"
      },

      {
         "dimensionSize" : "4", 
         "euroSize" : "36",
         "usSize" : "4"
      },
]
```

**Explanation of how array C is obtained** :
In array A there is one object that has key "size" with value **"UK-IND-3"** that contains the value **"3"** from the key "dimensionSize" in one of the object from array B.Same goes for object with key "size" value "**UK-IND-4**"

**My motive to find the solution to this problem** : I have huge length arrays and I need to run condition similar to above to filter out some data in a new array. I have seen other solutions in stack-overflow and I have derived a solution using array methods like filter, includes, some, map etc but I need an efficient solution that is efficient with real time data, like arrays with huge length.

Any help in sharing an efficient algorithm or a path-forward is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**Edit** : Existing solution that I have which runs in O(n^2). Assume A and B as arrays from my problem statement. **matchArray** is the resultant array.

```
let matchArray;
        matchArray = B.filter(objB => {
            let match = false;
            A.forEach(objA => {
                if (objA.size.includes(objB.dimensionSize) {
                    match = true;
                }
            });
            return match;
        });
```

**Edit 2** : Structure of array B and array C were not correct. I have corrected it now.

Comment: So what you have tried so far ? can you please post your code ?

Comment: @CodeManiac I have added it in now. Please check.

Comment: You will _always_ have to filter `B` on some condition, so `B.filter()` will remain, you just need to have a faster inner check for what B object to keep. To make that check happen in constant time, then you can loop through `A` to build up a lookup or Set or your condition, maybe with the full `size` string or just the number part, then check the B objects against that lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with O(n) complexity

```js
const solution = (A, B) => {
  const allowedSizes = new Set()
  
  A.forEach(({ size }) => {
    const [ s ] = size.match(/\d+$/g)
    
    allowedSizes.add(s)
  })
  
  return B.filter(({ dimensionSize }) => {
    return allowedSizes.has(dimensionSize)
  })
}

const A = [
      {
         "isAvailable" : true,
         "productCode" : "12103977",
         "size" : "UK/IND-3",
         "url" : "/asics-mens-gel-kayano-28-harmony-blue-running-shoes/12103977"
      },

      {
         "isAvailable" : true,
         "productCode" : "12103978",
         "size" : "UK/IND-4",
         "url" : "/asics-mens-gel-kayano-28-harmony-blue-running-shoes/12103978"
      },

      {
         "isAvailable" : true,
         "productCode" : "12103979",
         "size" : "UK/IND-8",
         "url" : "/asics-mens-gel-kayano-28-harmony-blue-running-shoes/12103979"
      },

]


const B = [
      {
         "dimensionSize" : "3",
         "euroSize" : "36",
         "usSize" : "4"
      },

      {
         "dimensionSize" : "4",
         "euroSize" : "36",
         "usSize" : "4"
      },

      {
         "dimensionSize" : "10",
         "euroSize" : "36",
         "usSize" : "4"
      },
]

console.log(solution(A, B))
```

Comment: I edited the structure of array B and array C in my problem statement as the structure was NOT correct earlier. Could you please check once and modify your solution.

Comment: I did, check please

Comment: Thank you.
Just on a side note - I feel bad thinking of times in past I have used O(n^2) in some other problems just because data set was quite small and I ignored the efficiency part. But now I strongly believe that efficiency is the most important thing whether at a small scale or at a big scale. It should never ever be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

All credits go to @kerm's answer, here is the adaptation to your updates with explanation:

1. Create a `Set` of `A[i].size` values - Set contains every value only once, in your example, the filterSet will contain (3,4,8) - this is done in O(n)

```
let filterSet = new Set();
A.forEach(i => filterSet.add(i.size.match(/\d+$/)[0]));
```

2. `Set` has a [has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) method which returns in O(1), which can be used in the `B.filter` method with O(n) complexity:

```
let result = B.filter(i => filterSet.has(i.dimensionSize))
```

Comment: Thank you. yes I accepted his answer.

One thing I wanted to ask separately that the solution in the problem statement is really O(n^2) ? It strikes to me that inside "forEach" there is an ".includes" so I think it's O(n^3). What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: @utkarsh-k Algoritmically you are right, but the interprets can make some internal optimizations (like to reuse the results of `A.forEach`), so it *might* be O(n^2) - you need to measure it empirically. JS provides objects like ArrayBuffer to do some lower level stuff, but generally there are little efficiency control in scripting languages. If you need max speed, you can create low-level library in C and then call it from scripts (not the case of JS in browser, though). Measure to see if the efforts pay off, O(n) is good enough.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a working example, first it creates an object with all available sizes in A, then filters B to keep only the ones that `dimensionSize` exist as key in `listedSizes`

```js
console.clear();
(()=>{

    let A = [{
        "isAvailable": true,
        "productCode": "12103977",
        "size": "UK/IND-3",
        "url": "/asics-mens-gel-kayano-28-harmony-blue-running-shoes/12103977"
    }, {
        "isAvailable": true,
        "productCode": "12103978",
        "size": "UK/IND-4",
        "url": "/asics-mens-gel-kayano-28-harmony-blue-running-shoes/12103978"
    }, {
        "isAvailable": true,
        "productCode": "12103979",
        "size": "UK/IND-8",
        "url": "/asics-mens-gel-kayano-28-harmony-blue-running-shoes/12103979"
    }, ]

    let B = [{
        "dimensionList": [{
            "dimensionSize": "3",
            "euroSize": "36",
            "usSize": "4"
        }]
    }, {
        "dimensionList": [{
            "dimensionSize": "4",
            "euroSize": "36",
            "usSize": "4"
        }]
    }, {
        "dimensionList": [{
            "dimensionSize": "10",
            "euroSize": "36",
            "usSize": "4"
        }]
    }];
    let listedSizes = Object.fromEntries(A.map(e=>[(e.size.match(/UK\/IND-(\d)+/) || [0, 0])[1],0]));
    let filteredB = B.filter(e=>listedSizes.hasOwnProperty(e.dimensionList[0].dimensionSize));

    console.log(listedSizes, filteredB);
}
)();
```